# Python: Finding elements in an array that fall within a range

Tags: python

I have an array and an integer

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
b = 3
```

I would like to find all elements in `a` that are within `+-diff` of `b`. If `diff=1` then I can do this using

```
d = np.where( (a == b - 1) | (a == b) | (a == b + 1) )
vals = a[d]
```

But what if `diff = 2`, or is undetermined and I want to create a function that has `diff` as an input?

I'm sure there must be a far more efficient and flexible way to code this than I have found.

I'm using Python 3.5

Answer (score 2):

You can use inequality expression:

```
a[ (b + diff >= a) & (a >= b - diff) ]
```

Comment: Thank you, sometimes the obvious is hard to see!